# Can user information be obtained from PID returned by devpay webservices or do I have to use s3 webservices for this?

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to take a look at an S3 user's information (like # of buckets, bucket size, etc.). My question: can I use the PersistentIdentifier (PID) returned by Devpay (ActivateHostedProduct) to see any other information about the user other than the user's subscription status?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the PID is only good for telling you if a devpay customer is subscribed to your product or not.